# Problem with differential equation in mathematica

Tags: differential-equations, numerics, interpolation

I am trying to solve the following differential equation:

$\frac{d^2φ}{dr^2} = -\frac{2}{r}\frac{dφ}{dr} + F(φ,r)$,

where $F(φ,r)$ is a very complicated expression that depends on $φ$ and $r$.

This can't be done analytically, so it must be done numerically.

What I tried to do is the following:

```
NDSolve[{x''[y] + 2/(y + 0.01)*x'[y] == Y1[x[y]], 
         x[0] == 0.4, 
         x'[0] == 0}, x, 
         {y, 0.1, 100}, 
         Method -> Automatic]
```

and then I wanted to plot the result. (The 0.01 in the denominator is fine, it's something we use in field theory.)

The problem is that *Mathematica* gives a solution, which is not what it should be from the theory and I guess it has to do with the following errors that appear when I try to solve the D.E.

[image: errors]

Are there any suggestions?

Thank you very much in advance for your time.

P.S: I should also have mentioned that I am using Mathematica 11.

P.S2: The form of Y1 is

```
3(-4.23777208123758`*^-7 E^(-7.0898154036220635` x Sqrt[1/(
      1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 \[Pi]))])
      DiracDelta[-4.5` + x] (x Sqrt[1/(1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 \[Pi]))])^(
     3/2) (1 + 0.26446386728801075`/(
       x Sqrt[1/(1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 \[Pi]))])) - 
    4.23777208123758`*^-7 E^(-7.0898154036220635` x Sqrt[1/(
      1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 \[Pi]))])
      HeavisideTheta[-4.5` + x] (x Sqrt[1/(
       1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 \[Pi]))])^(
     3/2) (-(0.26446386728801075`/(
        x^2 Sqrt[1/(1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 \[Pi]))])) - (
       0.002525443904885155` Sqrt[1/(1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 \[Pi]))])/
       x^2) - 4.23777208123758`*^-7 E^(-7.0898154036220635` x Sqrt[1/(
      1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 \[Pi]))])
      HeavisideTheta[-4.5` + x] (x Sqrt[1/(
       1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 \[Pi]))])^(
     3/2) (1 + 0.26446386728801075`/(
       x Sqrt[1/(
        1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 \[Pi]))])) (-7.0898154036220635` Sqrt[1/(
        1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 \[Pi]))] - 
       0.06770275002573074` (1/(1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 \[Pi])))^(3/2)) - 
    6.35665812185637`*^-7 E^(-7.0898154036220635` x Sqrt[1/(
      1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 \[Pi]))]) HeavisideTheta[-4.5` + x] Sqrt[
     x Sqrt[1/(
      1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 \[Pi]))]] (1 + 0.26446386728801075`/(
       x Sqrt[1/(1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 \[Pi]))])) (Sqrt[1/(
       1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 \[Pi]))] + (
       3 (1/(1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 \[Pi])))^(3/2))/(
       100 \[Pi])) + ((-HeavisideTheta[-4.5` + x] + 
         HeavisideTheta[-1.8` + x]) (-0.00003904000000000002` + 
         0.000035945364096363873` x Sqrt[1/(
          1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 \[Pi]))]) (-0.0013364302035827594` Sqrt[
          1/(1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 \[Pi]))] - 
         0.000012761968379850251` (1/(1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 \[Pi])))^(
          3/2) + (0.00009600000000000002` x)/(1 - (3 Log[x])/(
           50 \[Pi]))^2 + (0.01005309649148734` x)/(
         1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 \[Pi]))))/(0.0005219000000000003` - 
       0.0013364302035827594` x Sqrt[1/(
        1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 \[Pi]))] + (0.00502654824574367` x^2)/(
       1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 \[Pi])))^2 - ((-DiracDelta[-4.5` + x] + 
       DiracDelta[-1.8` + x]) (-0.00003904000000000002` + 
       0.000035945364096363873` x Sqrt[1/(
        1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 \[Pi]))]))/(
    0.0005219000000000003` - 
     0.0013364302035827594` x Sqrt[1/(1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 \[Pi]))] + (
     0.00502654824574367` x^2)/(
     1 - (3 Log[x])/(
      50 \[Pi]))) - ((-HeavisideTheta[-4.5` + x] + 
       HeavisideTheta[-1.8` + x]) (0.000035945364096363873` Sqrt[1/(
        1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 \[Pi]))] + 
       3.4325294263045497`*^-7 (1/(1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 \[Pi])))^(
        3/2)))/(0.0005219000000000003` - 
     0.0013364302035827594` x Sqrt[1/(1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 \[Pi]))] + (
     0.00502654824574367` x^2)/(1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 \[Pi]))) + 
    1/2 (-HeavisideTheta[-1.8` + x] + 
       HeavisideTheta[
        x]) (-0.005671852322897651` x^2 (1/(1 - Log[x]/100))^(3/2) - 
       0.000028359261614488252` x^2 (1/(1 - Log[x]/100))^(5/2) + (
       8.000000000000001`*^-6 x)/(1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 \[Pi]))^2 - (
       0.000015915494309189537` x^2 ((
          0.5026548245743668` x)/(1 - Log[x]/100)^2 + (
          100.53096491487337` x)/(1 - Log[x]/100)) (1 - Log[x]/
          100))/(1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 \[Pi]))^2 + (
       0.0008377580409572782` x)/(1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 \[Pi])) - (
       3 x^3 (-5.41` + 
          Log[(50.26548245743668` x^2)/(1 - Log[x]/100)]))/(
       31250 \[Pi] (1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 \[Pi]))^3) - (
       2 x^3 (-5.41` + 
          Log[(50.26548245743668` x^2)/(1 - Log[x]/100)]))/(
       625 (1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 \[Pi]))^2)) + 
    1/2 (-DiracDelta[-1.8` + x] + 
       DiracDelta[x]) (-0.00002193245422464303` - 
       0.0018906174409658836` x^3 (1/(1 - Log[x]/100))^(3/2) + (
       0.0004188790204786391` x^2)/(1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 \[Pi])) - (
       x^4 (-5.41` + 
          Log[(50.26548245743668` x^2)/(1 - Log[x]/100)]))/(
       1250 (1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 \[Pi]))^2))) + (
 4 \[Pi] x^4 (27/(25000 \[Pi] x (1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 \[Pi]))^2) + (
    39 Sec[1/2 Sqrt[13/
       3] (3.67407` + Log[1/(100 (1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 \[Pi])))])]^2)/(
    50000 \[Pi] x (1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 \[Pi]))^2) + (
    3 Sqrt[39]
      Tan[1/2 Sqrt[13/
       3] (3.67407` + Log[1/(100 (1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 \[Pi])))])])/(
    25000 \[Pi] x (1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 \[Pi]))^2)))/(1 - (3 Log[x])/(
   50 \[Pi]))^2 + (
 12 x^3 (9/(500 (1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 \[Pi]))) + (
    Sqrt[39] Tan[
      1/2 Sqrt[13/
       3] (3.67407` + Log[1/(100 (1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 \[Pi])))])])/(
    500 (1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 \[Pi])))))/(
 25 (1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 \[Pi]))^3) + (
 16 \[Pi] x^3 (9/(500 (1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 \[Pi]))) + (
    Sqrt[39] Tan[
      1/2 Sqrt[13/
       3] (3.67407` + Log[1/(100 (1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 \[Pi])))])])/(
    500 (1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 \[Pi])))))/(1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 \[Pi]))^2
```

Comment: What is Y1 and there is a syntax problem, why you use brackets for x[y] ?

Comment: Y1 is the F(φ,r). Sorry, I changed notation a bit. 
If I don't use the brackets, Mathematica says that the function x is with no arguments and does not solve it.

Comment: Your problem seems to be the definition of `Y1` therefore the question of @optimalcontrol. When I define `Y1[r_]:=r` it works like it should without any errors. We need to know Y1 to help you.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I have included the form of Y1 in the main post.

Comment: you will probably make that error go away if you define `Y1` to take only numeric arguments.  Then you will only throw an error in the unlikely event `x` hits "exactly" 4.5.  (I suspect your usage of delta   is ill posed.. )

Comment: Thank you. I'll try that and see what happens. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in the comment, you need to define `Y1` in a proper way, i.e,

```
Y1[x_] := paste your long expression here.
```

But still `NDSolve` gives an error,

> NDSolve::deltad: NDSolve cannot handle discontinuities where the argument of DiracDelta depends on any variable besides the temporal independent variable.

This can tackled by using `Method -> {"DiscontinuityProcessing" -> False}`.

Once again you will be face with another error,

> NDSolve::nlnum:

which show that there are complex numbers, to avoid this you can take `Re[Y1[x[y]]]`,

```
sol = NDSolve[{x''[y] + 2/(y + 0.01)*x'[y] == Re[Y1[x[y]]], x[0] == 0.4, x'[0] == 0}, x, 
{y, 0.1, 100}, Method -> {"DiscontinuityProcessing" -> False}]

Plot[x[y] /. sol, {y, 0.1, 100}]
```

[image]

Comment: notice you get the exact same result if you simplify `Y1` by setting all of the `DiracDelta` 's to zero.

Comment: Thank you for all the help guys. I really appreciate it. 
I got the same graph as this one, but the thing is that in theory it should not be that way. It should remain zero to infinity and not crossing to negative values. That's the problem.

Comment: Sorry, didn't know about that. And honestly didn't mean to offend you in any way.

Comment: @zhk I did it. I clicked the tick mark and the vote up

Comment: @george2079 Thanks for your nice suggestion.